# select a column with how many same value present

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

i have string data on my column

```
------------
name 
------------
john-yolo    
john-yolo    
john-yolo    
felix-goran  
carine-carin
carine-carin
```

i want to select name column with how many times the name present

ex :

```
------------
name 
------------
john-yolo-1    
john-yolo-2  
john-yolo-3    
felix-goran-1  
carine-carin-1
carine-carin-2
```

how can i produce data like that?

Comment: im using phpmyadmin from xampp 7.3.31, mariadb version 10.4.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MaraiDB supports ROW_NUMBER

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test
>     (`name` varchar(12))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO test
>     (`name`)
> VALUES
>
>     ('john-yolo'),
>     ('john-yolo'),
>     ('john-yolo'),
>     ('felix-goran'),
>     ('carine-carin'),
>     ('carine-carin')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(name,'-', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name)) as  name FROM test
> ```
>
> ```
> | name           |
> | :------------- |
> | carine-carin-1 |
> | carine-carin-2 |
> | felix-goran-1  |
> | john-yolo-1    |
> | john-yolo-2    |
> | john-yolo-3    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ef6652425a35cfaeb097f97182d65977)*

Comment: For others using MySQL 8.0 (as opposed to MariaDB), to prevent the `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'name' in 'window partition by'` error, you would want to add the table name or alias column identifier `PARTITION BY test.name`  [Db-Fiddle Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rAtPJLFZCmV1tRTGZYCZV7/0)

Comment: @WillB. name is no reserved word so the query runs as expected https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef6652425a35cfaeb097f97182d65977

Comment: Check the example I provided that is throwing the error and the one that is not.  It's not about the reserved name, but about the aliased column name. As it works fine outside of `CONCAT()`. The escaped sequence alias for the second query is not needed but just was added by habit.

Comment: @WillB. the site uses 8.0.12 that is very old to old for my taste

Comment: None-the-less still applicable to prevent the error when it arises.